# Get index of NSMenuItem (sender) in parent menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu, sender

I'm having a `NSMenu` (*application dock menu*) and several items in it with the same action.

How can I figure out the index of the sender item (the one triggering the action) within its container menu? (I'm not interesting in the `title`, since that might be a duplicate)

That's what I tried, but it keeps returning `0` (zero).

```
- (void)myAction:(id)sender
{
    NSMenuItem* mi = (NSMenuItem*)sender;

    int index = [[[mi parentItem] submenu] indexOfItem:mi];

    NSLog(@"Clicked item with index : %d",index);
}
```

Any ideas? (Is there any better approach to achieve the very same thing?)

Comment: Why not have the different menu items call different actions?

Comment: @RobKeniger Well, the menu is populated dynamically with variable content (and variable number of elements)... which are to be handled in a somewhat similar fashion... (actually a list of active document names - in a NON-traditional document-based app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the menu items' `representedObject` to store a reference to some object in your app. In your case, you would probably use the document that the menu item refers to:

```
[aMenuItem setRepresentedObject:yourDocument];
```

You could then access the object in the action like so:

```
- (void)myAction:(id)sender
{
    NSMenuItem* mi = (NSMenuItem*)sender;
    YourDocument* doc = (YourDocument*)[sender representedObject];
    //do something with doc
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea; although I'll still have to radically change the logic behind my menu population routines. I'll probably give it a try though! Thanks a lot! ;-)

Comment: I finally made it by passing the `index` number to the `keyEquivalent` property of each `NSMenuItem` at creation time. ;-)

Comment: That's kind of abusing the `keyEquivalent`. If you just want the index, then it would be better to store the index as an `NSNumber` and then store that `NSNumber` object as the menu item's `representedObject`.